# Python List Question: Which part of code is more logical?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

```
list_of_names = ['Vladimir', 'Victor', 'Alexander', 'Darius', 'Dimitriy']

#1
for list in list_of_names:
  print(list)
# 2
for list in range(len(list_of_names)):
  print(list_of_names[list])
```

Which part(#1 or #2) is better to announce value?
Which will be correct?

Comment: Please read [ask], [mre], [Why should I not upload images of ... when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: What topics can I ask about... https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: The first for loop is the canonical way to iterate over a sequence. Did you spend any time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)?

Comment: Yes, dear. I just want to know what (#1 or #2) will be better to use? And if i use "range" python will process to code more slowly or nope? how can i detect this?  Thats interesting for me. About canonical way , ok i know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#1 Is suitable for showing the list elements in general
#2 Is good for printing either all of the elements or setting limits for starting point, ending point, and steps. ==> range(start, end, steps)

If you want to print all of the elements of the list use #1 and if you want to print certain elements range or in specific steps use #2

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly using less functions and code for the first loop and they both return the same thing. The second code is also more clear and easer to read so no one will get confused.